# OPC UA Server Subscription implementation C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-4.0, opc-ua

I am new to OPC UA Server Implementation.

I want o implement SubscriptionManager_SubscriptionCreated event in OPC UA Server using C#

Could you please share me the code? How can I implement subscription mechanism in OPC UA Server?

```
**private static void SubscriptionManager_SubscriptionCreated(IUAServerSubscription subscription, bool deleted)
{
 if (subscription == null)
 {
 throw new ArgumentNullException("subscription");
 }
}**
```

Comment: Hello, can you may write some more details what you like to do? So fare I know, subscriptions are used on a OPC-UA Client to listen on changes from the OPC-UA Server. Did you use a SDK for OPC-UA implementation?